Finding an explicit irreducible representation using idempotents and characters
I'm learning representation theory for the first time, and trying to work out the details of some representations. Using character theory, I was able to figure out that the character table of $S_3$ is the following:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
     & 1 & (1, 2) & (1, 2, 3)\\
     \hline
    |C_i| & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
    \hline
    \chi_1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    \chi_2 & 1 & -1 & 1\\
    \chi_3 & 2 & 0 & -1\\
    \hline
\end{array}$$
where the top row lists the conjugacy classes, the second row lists the size of each conjugacy class, and the other rows are the characters.
From this, I would like to reconstruct the submodules of the group ring $\mathbb{C}[S_3]$ where $S_3$ acts with character $\chi_i$. From what I've gathered from other posts on this website, this can be done by noting that if we have a representation $V$ that decomposes as $V = \bigoplus_i n_iV_i$, the projection $\pi_i : V \rightarrow V_i$ is given by multiplication by the element of the group ring $\frac{\chi_i(e)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G}\chi_i(g) * g$. But when I tried this for example with $\chi_3$ on $S_3$, I found that the matrix corresponding to multiplication by this element was the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-1}{3} & \frac{-1}{3}\\
    0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{-1}{3} & \frac{-1}{3} & 0 & 0\\
    0 & \frac{-1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{-1}{3} & 0 & 0\\
    0 & \frac{-1}{3} & \frac{-1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0\\
    -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{-1}{3}\\
    -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{bmatrix}$$
which, after I did column operations on it, I discovered was full rank and thus can't be the matrix of a projection onto a proper $2$ dimensional subspace.
Am I misunderstanding how to approach a problem like this? If so, what's the correct way to find the submodules $V_i$s from the character table and knowing $V$? And what do all of the other posts that describe $\frac{\chi_i(e)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g) * g$ as an idempotent mean if they're not saying that it's a projection onto the irreducible representation?
Thanks for the help!


if we have a representation $V$ that decomposes as $V = \bigoplus_i n_iV_i$, the projection $\pi_i : V \rightarrow V_i$ is given by multiplication by the element of the group ring $\frac{\chi_i(e)}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G}\chi_i(g) * g$

First, the isotypical projector uses the summand $\chi_i(g^{-1})g$ in general (or equivalently $\chi_i(g)g^{-1}$), although we have $\chi_i(g^{-1})=\overline{\chi_i(g)}$ which is the same as $\chi_i(g)$ for real representations.
Second, it is a projection onto $n_iV_i=\overbrace{V_i\oplus\cdots\oplus V_i}^{n_i}$, not onto any one particular copy of $V_i$. So this isotypical projector projects onto a subspace of dimension $4$.
Viewing $\mathbb{R}[S_3]\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^3{\rm End}(V_i)$, this is projection onto ${\rm End}(V_3)\cong V_3\oplus V_3^\ast\cong M_2(\mathbb{R})$. In fact, this is even true as a $S_3\times S_3$-rep! (Usually this sort of application of Artin-Wedderburn needs to use $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ but all irreps of $S_3$ are real so this all works over $\mathbb{R}$ in this case.)
In general, there is no unique decomposition into $V_i$-irreps of $nV_i$, even if the notation may seem to suggest it. The copies of $kV_i$ in $nV_i$ (where $m\le n$) are parameterized by the Grassmanian ${\rm Gr}(n,k)$, i.e. correspond bijectively to $k$-dim subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Indeed, if we view $nV_i$ as $V_i\otimes\mathbb{R}^n$ (where $\mathbb{R}^n$ is trivial), the subreps are all of the form $V_i\otimes W$ where $W\le\mathbb{R}^n$ is a subspace.

[...] I found that the matrix corresponding to multiplication by this was [matrix]

The diagonals should have $\frac{2}{3}$s not $\frac{1}{3}$s.
This should have rank $4$, and whose kernel is the span of the other two isotypical components. Since the other two irreps are 1D, so the isotypical components of $\mathbb{R}[S_3]$ are also 1D, which means we can apply the isotypical projectors with $i=1,2$ to get that the other two components (which together span the kernel of the third projector) are spanned by the first two projectors respectively.

Thank you! I did indeed have the diagonal entries wrong.
